# Workflow task sent to same person multiple times

Tags: sharepoint-server

We use SharePoint for a project at work. Last year, when we set up our Workflows (as a Collect Feedback), we were able to put the boss in charge in as the recipient 8 times (the boss would manually reassign the task to someone each time it came back to them, because people change around). This year, I am attempting to create our Workflows the same way but when I enter the same person 8 times consistently, it wipes it out. It seems since the last update, it will only allow the same person in there once, or at least in a row. Does anyone have any ideas of how to change this, or a solution to add one person only multiple times?

Thanks!